# How to check a statement inside other method

Tags: java

I am using a while loop for checking input, and then repeating until relevant conditions are satisfyied (the commented-out code). But since I have a lot of inputs I decided to make a method for that, and it works perfect(not commented code). Problem is when I want to input a `currentnumber`, which shouldn't be greater than `boughtNumber`. The old way worked for that, but now I can't pass that statement to the `inputCheck` method. How could I make this work, or replace it with another better approach. Not sure if java supports "assert", can I use it here.

**MyMethod**

```
public void save() throws IOException{
        String name = "";
        String boughtNumber = "", currentNumber = "";
        String buyPrice = "", sellPrice = "";

        name = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite naziv artikla:\t\t", "string", true, false);
        boughtNumber = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite nabavnu kolicinu:\t", "int", true, false);
        currentNumber = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite trenutnu kolicinu:\t", "int", true, Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) > Integer.parseInt(boughtNumber));
        buyPrice = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite nabavnu cijenu:\t\t", "float", true, false);
        sellPrice = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite prodajnu cijenu:\t", "float", true, false);

//      while(name == null || patternString.matcher(name).matches()==false) {
//          System.out.print("Unesite naziv artikla:\t\t");
//          name = input.nextLine();            
//      }
//      while(boughtNumber == null || patternInt.matcher(boughtNumber).matches()==false) {
//          System.out.print("Unesite nabavnu kolicinu:\t");
//          boughtNumber = input.nextLine();
//      }
//      
//      while(currentNumber == null || patternInt.matcher(currentNumber).matches()==false || Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) > Integer.parseInt(boughtNumber)) {    
//          System.out.print("Unesite trenutnu kolicinu:\t");
//          currentNumber = input.nextLine();
//      }
//      
//      while(buyPrice == null || patternFloat.matcher(buyPrice).matches()==false) {
//          System.out.print("Unesite nabavnu cijenu:\t\t");
//          buyPrice = input.nextLine();
//      }
//      
//      while(sellPrice == null || patternFloat.matcher(sellPrice).matches()==false) {
//          System.out.print("Unesite prodajnu cijenu:\t");
//          sellPrice = input.nextLine();   
//      }
```

**class with inputCheck method**

```
package hr.atos.praksa.josipmaricevic.zadatak15;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Functions {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final static private Pattern patternNotBlank = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
    final static private Pattern patternOIB = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{11}$");
    final static private Pattern patternString = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]*");
    final static private Pattern patternInt = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");
    final static private Pattern patternFloat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([.]?[0-9]+|[0-9]*)");

    public static String inputCheck(String print, String _pattern, boolean andStatement, boolean orStatement ) {
        String string = "";
        Pattern pattern = patternFloat;

        switch(_pattern) {
        case "int":
            pattern = patternInt;
            break;
        case "float":
            pattern = patternFloat;
            break;
        case "string":
            pattern = patternString;
            break;
        case "oib":
            pattern = patternOIB;
            break;
        case "notblank":
            pattern = patternNotBlank;
            break;
        }

        while((andStatement && pattern.matcher(string).matches()==false) || orStatement){
            System.out.print(print);
            string = input.nextLine();          
        }


        return string;
    }


}
```

I can clarify if something is not clear about it.

Comment: See [Oracle's enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for info on how to avoid this problem altogether. Also, is there a reason `boughtNumber` isn't an `ìnt`, `buyPrice` not a `double`, and so on?

Comment: How does the `inputCheck()` method terminate when the `orStatement` parameter is true?

Comment: Now it doesn't terminate,and that is actually a problem now, a need to put a whole statement instead of orStatement, but i do not know how.

Comment: Not sure how enum can help me here

Comment: With an enum you can make sure your not dependent on always typeing int,float,string,oid,notblank right, also it will make it impossible to have a _pattern value different from the defined enum values (now I could for example call the method and give 'funnyType' as _pattern value, that's probably the tip @AustinSchäfer was trying to give you

Comment: I think you didn't understand what is my problem there, but it's solved now, ty for help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to look into predicates for this.

predicates are functions that specify if a certain input is OK or not, and can be chained

for example:

```
final static private Pattern patternInt = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");

    static Predicate isNumber = input -> patternInt.matcher((String)input).matches();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println();

        Predicate numberOver50 = isNumber.and(input -> Integer.parseInt((String)input)>50);

        test(numberOver50,"50");
        test(numberOver50,"51");

    }
    static void test(Predicate test,String input){
        System.out.println(test.test(input));
    }
```

rewriting this Functions class this would give following changes:

```java
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final static private Predicate<String> patternNotBlank = input -> Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(input).matches();
    final static private Predicate<String> patternOIB = input -> Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{11}$").matcher( input).matches();
    final static private Predicate<String> patternInt = input -> Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$").matcher( input).matches();
    final static private Predicate<String> patternString = input -> Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]*").matcher(input).matches();
    final static private Predicate<String> patternFloat = input -> Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([.]?[0-9]+|[0-9]*)").matcher(input).matches();

    public static String inputCheck(String print, String _pattern, Predicate andStatement, Predicate orStatement ) {
        Predicate<String> typeTest = patternFloat;
        if (andStatement==null){
            andStatement = input -> true;// a passthrough, always true
        }
        if (orStatement==null){
            orStatement = input -> false;// a passthrough, always true
        }

        switch(_pattern) {
            case "int":
                typeTest = patternInt;
                break;
            case "float":
                typeTest = patternFloat;
                break;
            case "string":
                typeTest = patternString;
                break;
            case "oib":
                typeTest = patternOIB;
                break;
            case "notblank":
                typeTest = patternNotBlank;
                break;
        }

        String string;
        do {
            System.out.print(print);
            string = input.nextLine();
        } while (andStatement.and(typeTest.negate()).or(orStatement).test(string));

        return string;
    }
```

now you can add the extra test when declaring the function:

```
Predicate NOEND = input -> true;
Preducate NOOR = input -> false;
...

currentNumber = Functions.inputCheck("Unesite trenutnu kolicinu:\t", "int",NOEND, input->{return Integer.parseInt((String)input)> Integer.parseInt(boughtNumber)};
```

be aware, variables used in functions need to be 'final' (effective final, which isn't always the same as a type predefined as final!)

Also the function will be defined when you write it, so the boughtNumber must be filled in at that time, if you changed the ordering to first get currentNumber and then boughtNumber it will not be valid as boughtNumber isn't yet filled in, and isn't effective final (will change later in the method!)

EDIT: by defining the Predicate classes with  no extra casting is needed. (changed the example code to show this.)

Comment: What is the difference between Predicate and Preducate, or it's just typo error??

Comment: just a typo, sorry